# Redmine 2.4.2 served via Apache mod_fcgid returns Error 500

Tags: ruby, apache, redmine, fastcgi

I'm trying to upgrade Redmine from v 2.3.1 to v 2.4.2 maintaining the same configuration for serving it: Apache with mod_fcgi.

My configuration is the following:

Environment:

- Redmine version                2.4.2.stable
- Ruby version                   1.8.7-p358 (2012-02-08) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails version                  3.2.16
- Environment                    production
- Database adapter               Mysql2

Debian 7.3 with Apache 2.2.22-13. I've tested redmine via webrick without any problem, but I can't make it works via fastcgi.

dispatch.fcgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this sounds ridiculous, but try `sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8`
(You might also have to install the 1.8 versions of the gems you're using)

Comment: I already have done this step before. The site is currently running with the 2.3.1 version.